# Germany Residence Permit away for many days

Tags: germany, resident-permit

I have a residence permit of Germany. I want to work in another country but maintain my residence in Germany. Is it possible that I visit Germany twice a year to maintain my permit? Visiting Germany every 179 days makes the Residence Permit invalid? Or it must be that I stay in Germany for a total of 180 days in a year to maintain my residence permit(limited: Aufenthaltstitel, purpose: study)?

For example I stay out of Germany (as well as EU) for 170 days. Stay in Germany for the next 20 days then again out for 170 days and then come back. In this case the Permit gets invalid or not?

Comment: Is it a limited or unlimited permit?  That is, is it an *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* or a *Niederlassungserlaubnis*?  And is your intended "other country" part of the EU (excluding the UK, Ireland, and Denmark)?

Comment: it is a limited permit: Aufenthaltserlaubnis. Other country is outside of EU (and other European countries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Aufenthaltserlaubnis** gets invalidated 6 months after leaving Germany. If you return to Germany within the 6 months, it stays valid.

**BUT** there is a caveat. If you leave Germany for an *in its nature non-temporary cause* [§ 51 AufenthG, Abs. 1.6](https://dejure.org/gesetze/AufenthG/51.html), the *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* gets invalid **the moment you leave Germany.** Having a job in another country typically is such an *in its nature non-temporary cause.*

There are extra provisions for people that are

- development aid volunteers
- family member of German diplomates
- students of a German university
- workers for a foreign branch of a German company

But for these, you have to file an application at your local *Ausländerbehörde*.

Comment: Thanks. But I have a following situation:

I am enrolled as a PhD student in a German University. And I got a job in a country outside EU. The point is that I would be visiting my supervisor in Germany every 5th month.

So in this case my Residence Permit expires?

Comment: If you have a job outside Germany, the standard *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* expires **as soon you leave Germany** (**not** after 6 months only). You need a special permit from the *Ausländerbehörde*, they do that for PhD students.